# windows mobile 6 sdk install issue

Tags: visual-studio-2013, installation, windows-mobile-6.1

I have visual studio 2013 professional.

I want to install windows mobile sdk 6, but the error is:

**Not Installed: Visual Studio 2005 SP1 or Later**

How can I install mobile 6 sdk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use VS 2008 to address devices running on Windows Mobile 6.x